# Android game development structure

Tags: java, android, structure

I would like to develop a game on Android platform, I have about a year experience with Java and also used the OpenGL library in C++. I also programmed Minesweeper and Connect Four in Java. Basically, here's the type of game I want to create:

[image: example sketch of game layout]

Pressing the screen would make your character go up in the screen and releasing it will make it go down. I know there are games like this already but it doesn't matter to me, it's my current goal.

The structure of both games I programmed was quite easy, it was only a GridLayout. This wouldn't fit in any defined layout. Then, I have absolutely no idea how to test a character/environment collision. I'm also wondering what would be the easiest/fastest way to draw the "collision" environment, I assume it would be with OpenGL but from what I know, it would still take a long time and wouldn't be that easy.

I've been trying to find a tutorial about this but obviously, I've been unsuccessful.

PS: I already know the basics to make an Android app so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: You may have better luck at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware there was a such section, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

think about each segment of what you're trying to achieve individually.

First off, you could probably read up on libgdx: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/
it's a great android game engine which will do alot for the work for you.

For the player, think of it as just incrementing the players y position by a few pixels if it's pressed down, else decrement it.

For the map, you'd probably need some sort of 2d polygon based collision for the upper and lower collideable environments, libgdx has a physics library built in but i'm not sure how the support it for polygon-based collision. And finally, just create the map and make it wider than your game screen, and just move the camera along as the player moves.

Comment: I would have to agree that libgdx is a good starting point. In addition you can do all your programming using java on desktop.  Then switch on in both Android and HTML5.